# Finding an array of object using lodash not working

Tags: angular, lodash

I have a service which has an array of objects. One of the methods in that service is to return one object based on the `id` passed to that method as a parameter. I'm using lodash to find the particular object and it's not working.

Code:

PortfolioService.ts

```
portfolios: PortfolioModel[] = [
  {
    id: 13,
    image: '../../assets/images/portfolio/07-chick.png'
  },
  {
    id: 14,
    image: '../../assets/images/portfolio/04-cat.png'
  },
  {
    id: 15,
    image: '../../assets/images/portfolio/01-dog.png'
  }
];
...
getPortfolio(id: number): Observable<PortfolioModel> {
  const tmp = _.find(this.portfolios, (x) => x.id === id);
  console.log(id);
  return(of<PortfolioModel>(tmp));
}
```

Here I'm getting the parameter as `13` or `14` but when I console the tmp, it says `undefined`. Anything wrong with my code?

Comment: Where you are consoling the tmp var in the code?

Comment: I tried consoling the tmp, then I thought whether the id is undefined, that's why i checked the id in this code.

Comment: is id undefined when you try to console it?

Comment: Can you share portfolio.service.ts with import statement. Please check here, I am able to log tmp https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yjlpvy

Comment: @Ranjith Varatharajan- I tried your example and it works perfectly, when you pass 13 to **getPortfolio** as parameter , it returns the object with id 13

Comment: got it. the code is right, i'm passing the number as string instead of number. dumb me.